# setting a output limit in rss-feed

Tags: php

I want to set a limit for the output but I don't know how and where. Can anyone help me?

The code (excerpt):

```
// Editable values
// Show how many items, defaults to 10?
$max   = 8; 

// Fetch the items
if (!isset($actions) || empty($actions))
   $actions = fillActionArray($datestart, $dateend, $section_id);

//Generating the news items
if (is_array($actions)){
foreach($actions as $item){
// Build url like : pages/kalendar.php?year=1900&month=01&day=03&id=2&detail=1

    $ds = $item['date_start'];
    $link = $page_link.'?year='.(substr($ds,0,4)).'&amp;month='.(substr($ds,5,2)).'&amp;day='.(substr($ds,8,2)).'&amp;id='.$item['id'].'&amp;detail=1'; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array chunk on that news items variable "actions" based on the $max value http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

check the output of this -> print_r(array_chunk($actions, $max));

Comment: sorry, I am not a coder. That's why I need a comleted code.

Answer (score 0):

This is for me the simplest way:

```
//Generating the news items
$i=0;

if (is_array($actions)){
   foreach($actions as $item)
if ($i < $max) {
// Build url like : pages/kalendar.php?year=1900&month=01&day=03&id=2&detail=1 
    $ds = $item['date_start'];
$link = $page_link.'?year='.(substr($ds,0,4)).'&amp;month='.(substr($ds,5,2)).'&amp;day='.(substr($ds,8,2)).'&amp;id='.$item['id'].'&amp;detail=1';
$i +=1; 
?>
```